# Fetching data from MySQL using MATCH and AGAINST & limiting the result to have one entry from a column of similar name

Tags: php, mysql, match-against

I have a table where in there is COLUMN 'name' and another COLUMN 'description'.

```
--- Name ---|--- Description ---

------- John | abc123

------- John | def456

------- John | ghi789

------- Terry | abc123

------- Terry | def456

------- Terry | ghi789
```

When I use a **MATCH AGAINST** I get **3** outputs. What I need is to have only **1** value returned.

Also I have a page for '***John***' where all the 3 '***description***' are given so I can't use

```
     SELECT John WHERE description = 'abc123';
```

Using this for ***Search*** so for a $searchquery of **'john terry'** the output I am trying to get is $row['name'] should be ('john', 'terry')

I just need it to be one output i.e, **"John"** & **"Terry"** and not **3 times** **"John"** and **3 times** **"Terry"** which I would fetch via `mysql_fetch_array` and use the array in a `while` loop.

Please suggest if it is possible to do so.

Thanks in advance for your time and response.

Happy Coding!

Comment: simply use LIMIT 1 in your query to get only one result

Comment: Thanx but actually I have an issue with that coz I am searching the database and I have updated the question please be kind enough to go thru it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY`.

So your query would be:

```
SELECT name FROM tableName WHERE MATCH(name) AGAINST("' . $searchQuery . '") GROUP BY name;
```

It would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

use `limit 1` at the end of your match against query to limit to one result

Comment: Thanx for your time. But I have a different issue, as I am using loop and searching thru database so I need to LIMIT it to 1 for one 'name' and then LIMIT it for another 'name' with one query

Comment: Its not a new question I just didnt explain it the with explicit details.

Comment: select group_concat(distinct name)